# No arrowheads in PGF (Linux Mint 18)

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, linux

No arrowheads show up in pfg or tikz when using latex on Linux Mint 18. The code below should produce an arrow, but only produces a line. The code is correct, since it works in Mint 17.3 as well as in Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04.

I get no error messages or warnings. The problem appears both with pdflatex and latex+dvips. I have even upgraded to a newer latex than supported in Mint 18, but it didn't help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{10cm}{5cm}
    \pgfsetendarrow{\pgfarrowtriangle{2mm}}
    \pgfxyline(0,1)(2,1)
  \end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: those earlier versions have a very outdated version of TikZ that's why

Answer (score 3):

`\pgfsetendarrow` and `\pgfxyline` seems to be undocumented in the `pgf`/TikZ manual, version 3.0.1a. The macros are only defined in `pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty`. `\pgfsetendarrow` defines the macro `\pgf@endarrow`, but this macro is never used in more recent versions of `pgf`. The solution is the use of documented arrow commands, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{10cm}{5cm}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{Triangle[width=2mm]}
    \pgfxyline(0,1)(2,1)
  \end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. I have an older manual and didn't know there were fundamental changes without backwards compatibility. I wonder, though, if there is some simple way to get compatibility with earlier versions, since I often use old figures and modify?

Comment: @chrba `\@ifpackagelater` (e.g. `\makeatletter\@ifpackagelater{pgfcorearrows.code.tex}{2015/05/14}{...}{...}\makeatother` can be used for macro definitions that hide the changed syntax of the arrow macros. The correct date is probably earlier; the source code history, NEWS, ... would need to be analyzed.

Comment: Thanks again, but that solution seems to require a separate fix for every problem that turns up. I realize now that this is much bigger problem than I realized, since the old and new versions are not compatible in either direction. I must have compatible versions at home and at work, and it must also be compatible with my coauthors at other places, and with publishers. As long as everybody else is using the older version, I will have to stick to that. I suppose I must either try to install an older version, or revert to Mint 17.3.